# When NOT to use an interface or abstract class?

Tags: oop

I am creating class that is going to back out taxes and give you a before tax value.  This is just a simple concrete class, no interfaces or abstract classes involved, but I keep thinking that maybe I should implement and interface or abstract class and inherit from that because what if one days someone says, "I do not implement backing out taxes that way", I do it another way, so then I have to create another class or method for that person.  So my question is, how do you know when you should create and abstract class or interface.  What if at design time, you really don't know what to do? Should you just do it to cover yourself later?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depends on your philosphy. The Extreme Programming crowd (XP) say "YAGNI" (You ain't gonna need it) and recommend not to implement anything unless you're actually going to use it. However, since you're already foreseeing people computing taxes in different ways, you do need to take that into account, and make your `ComputeTax` method virtual.

Comment: Well, right now I don't see people doing it a different way, but I could be wrong, so as I said in the post, would it be better to just do it from the beginning just to cover the scenario.  Out of curiosity, if I create an interface, why do I need to mark the method as virtual, isn't it virtual by default.

Comment: The Extreme Programming crowd also are big on testing and mock objects. Mock objects mean lots of interfaces even if they aren't used in the code proper.

Comment: @Xaisoft: depending on your language, you may or may not need to mark the methods virtual. For instance, in C++ if you create an interface class (actually, a pure abstract class), the method in the class that implements the interface is automatically virtual.

Answer (score 0):

The interface is almost always good idea. You know what your class will be doing so why not to put the public part in an interface so anyone (especially you later on) can benefit from the code written using this class and referecing it with the interface?

Comment: Not really. It might add unnecessary complexity.

Comment: Just as said above. Especially in small, easy projects using an interface might unnecesarily bloat and pollute the code.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is the way you are asking the question, the example you use. Whether or not an interface is needed depends on the *context*, the class using the object, not on the type of the object itself.

So in the case you present... "I'm writing some code that needs to back out taxes to give a before tax value. Should this code care how the taxes are backed out?" If no, then the code you are writing should use an interface, otherwise it shouldn't. If the code that needs to call the "backoutTaxes" method doesn't care how those taxes are backed out, then there should be an interface for your BackoutTaxClass to implement.